# MySQL and subquery returns no results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL database and SQL query which is not 100% cleaned up yet, but that is not the biggest problem. The main problem is a subquery which is not working as I wish. Please see below.

```
SELECT
  sarjojen_rglistat.montako_huonointa_pois_lkm AS ei_huomioitavat_kilpailut_lkm
  , sarjojen_rglistat.montako_suora_nousu_lkm AS montako_suora_nousu_lkm
  , sarjojen_rglistat.montako_suora_pudotus_lkm AS montako_suora_pudotus_lkm
  , sarjojen_rglistat.montako_nousukarsinta_lkm AS montako_nousukarsinta_lkm
  , sarjojen_rglistat.montako_pudotuskarsinta_lkm AS montako_pudotuskarsinta_lkm
  , sarjojen_rglistat.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id AS vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id
  , sarjojen_rglistat.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id AS epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id
  , sarjojen_rglistojen_osakilpailut.monesko_kilpailu AS monesko_kilpailu
  , sarjojen_rglistojen_osakilpailut.sarakeotsikko AS kilpailu_sarakeotsikko
  , sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet.kayttaja_id AS kayttaja_id
  , sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet.pistemaara AS pisteet
  , sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet.kompensaatiopistemaara AS kompensaatiopisteet
  , kilpailukausien_kilpailut.id AS kilpailu_id
  , kilpailukausien_kilpailut.ajankohta_alkamispaiva AS kilpailu_alkamispaiva
  , kilpailukausien_kilpailut.kilpailunimi_virallinen AS kilpailu_nimi
  , kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.pelaaja_oma_nimi_txt AS kayttaja_nimiteksti
  , kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.pelaaja_oma_seura_lyh_txt AS kayttaja_seurateksti
  , kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.pelaaja_oma_kunta_txt AS kayttaja_kuntateksti
  , sarjojen_kilpailukaudet.kausi_id AS kausi_id

FROM (sarjojen_rglistat
    , sarjojen_rglistojen_osakilpailut
    , kilpailukausien_kilpailut
    , sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet
    , sarjojen_kilpailukaudet
    , sarjojen_kilpailukausien_kilpailusysteemit)
    /* , kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset */
    /* , sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset */

LEFT OUTER JOIN sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset
ON (sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset.sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sarjojen_rglistat.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id)

LEFT OUTER JOIN kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset
ON (sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset.kayttaja_id = kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.kayttaja_id)

WHERE
  sarjojen_rglistat.id = 4
  AND sarjojen_rglistojen_osakilpailut.rglista_id = sarjojen_rglistat.id
  AND sarjojen_rglistojen_osakilpailut.kilpailu_id = kilpailukausien_kilpailut.id
  AND sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet.kilpailu_id = kilpailukausien_kilpailut.id

  AND sarjojen_kilpailukausien_kilpailusysteemit.id = kilpailukausien_kilpailut.kauden_kilpailusysteemi_id
  AND sarjojen_kilpailukausien_kilpailusysteemit.sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sarjojen_kilpailukaudet.id

  AND kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.kayttaja_id = sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet.kayttaja_id
  AND kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.kilpailu_id = sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet.kilpailu_id

  AND kilpailukausien_kilpailut.kausi_id IS NULL
  AND kilpailukausien_kilpailut.seura_id IS NULL

  AND ((sarjojen_rglistat.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id IS NULL AND sarjojen_rglistat.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id IS NULL) || 
      (sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset.sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sarjojen_rglistat.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id AND sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset.kayttaja_id = kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.kayttaja_id) || 

      (sarjojen_rglistat.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id IS NOT NULL
      AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset
        WHERE   kayttaja_id = kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.kayttaja_id
                AND sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sarjojen_rglistat.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id
        )
      ))

  ORDER BY sarjojen_kilpailukaudet.kausi_id ASC, kilpailukausien_kilpailut.ajankohta_alkamispaiva ASC, kilpailukausien_kilpailut.id ASC
```

The problem is the following part of my code. It should return a row in two cases:

1) if `sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset = sarjojen_rglistat.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id`

or

2) `sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset = sarjojen_rglistat.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id` does not exist.

```
  (sarjojen_rglistat.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id IS NOT NULL
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset
    WHERE   kayttaja_id = kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.kayttaja_id
            AND sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sarjojen_rglistat.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id
    )
  ))
```

Now it returns no results. How could I solve the problem?

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Could you show me how to do it?

Comment: @xms: You already know how to do it. For outer joins you are already using it (`LEFT OUTER JOIN ... ON`, but for inner joins (`INNER JOIN ... ON` you don't.

Comment: Your query would also be more readable, if you used table aliases, e.g. `LEFT OUTER JOIN kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset ki ON skp.kayttaja_id = ki.kayttaja_id` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset ON (sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset.kayttaja_id = kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.kayttaja_id)`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Sorry, but where are my inner joins?

Comment: An inner join is the normal join of two tables on some criteria. E.g. `FROM sarjojen_rglistat sr INNER JOIN sarjojen_rglistojen_osakilpailut sro ON AND sro.rglista_id = sr.id`.

Comment: `(sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset.sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sarjojen_rglistat.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id)` forces the `LEFT OUTER JOIN sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset` to perfom like INNER

Comment: @Serg: Yes, I was about to mention this ;-)

Comment: @Serg Good to know. How could I avoid this?

Comment: Place the predicate into ON clause

Comment: `kayttaja_id` exists in `sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset` and `sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet`, but your `ON` clause doesn't contain `sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset.kayttaja_id = sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet.kayttaja_id`. Is this on purpose?

Comment: @Serg Now I have `LEFT OUTER JOIN sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset as pelaajastatukset
ON pelaajastatukset.sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sarjojen_rglistat.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id`. Is this what you tried to say?

Comment: Not  sure exactly, it totally depends on the result you need. Most probably the predicate moved from WHERE should be ANDed with the initial predicate in ON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So either `skk.sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sr.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id` or `NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM skp WHERE skp.kayttaja_id = ki.kayttaja_id)`? Okay, I've applied this condition in the following query.

I'm using table aliases to make it all more radable. I've also re-written your joins. Please check them.

```
SELECT
  sr.montako_huonointa_pois_lkm AS ei_huomioitavat_kilpailut_lkm
  , sr.montako_suora_nousu_lkm AS montako_suora_nousu_lkm
  , sr.montako_suora_pudotus_lkm AS montako_suora_pudotus_lkm
  , sr.montako_nousukarsinta_lkm AS montako_nousukarsinta_lkm
  , sr.montako_pudotuskarsinta_lkm AS montako_pudotuskarsinta_lkm
  , sr.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id AS vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id
  , sr.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id AS epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id
  , sro.monesko_kilpailu AS monesko_kilpailu
  , sro.sarakeotsikko AS kilpailu_sarakeotsikko
  , sor.kayttaja_id AS kayttaja_id
  , sor.pistemaara AS pisteet
  , sor.kompensaatiopistemaara AS kompensaatiopisteet
  , kk.id AS kilpailu_id
  , kk.ajankohta_alkamispaiva AS kilpailu_alkamispaiva
  , kk.kilpailunimi_virallinen AS kilpailu_nimi
  , ki.pelaaja_oma_nimi_txt AS kayttaja_nimiteksti
  , ki.pelaaja_oma_seura_lyh_txt AS kayttaja_seurateksti
  , ki.pelaaja_oma_kunta_txt AS kayttaja_kuntateksti
  , sk.kausi_id AS kausi_id
FROM sarjojen_rglistat sr
JOIN sarjojen_rglistojen_osakilpailut sro ON sro.rglista_id = sr.id
JOIN kilpailukausien_kilpailut kk ON  kk.id = sro.kilpailu_id
                                  AND kk.kausi_id IS NULL
                                  AND kk.seura_id IS NULL
JOIN sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet sor ON sor.kilpailu_id = kk.id
JOIN sarjojen_kilpailukausien_kilpailusysteemit skk 
                ON skk.id = kk.kauden_kilpailusysteemi_id
JOIN sarjojen_kilpailukaudet sk ON sk.id = skk.sarjan_kilpailukausi_id
LEFT JOIN sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset skp
                ON  skp.sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sr.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id
                AND skp.kayttaja_id  = sor.kayttaja_id
LEFT JOIN kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset ki ON  ki.kayttaja_id = sor.kayttaja_id
                                         AND ki.kilpailu_id = sor.kilpailu_id
WHERE sr.id = 4
AND 
(
  (
    sr.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id IS NULL 
    AND 
    sr.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id IS NULL
  ) 
  OR 
  (
    skp.sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sr.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id 
    AND 
    skp.kayttaja_id = ki.kayttaja_id
  )
  OR
  (
    skk.sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sr.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id
    OR 
    NOT EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT *
      FROM skp
      WHERE skp.kayttaja_id = ki.kayttaja_id
    )
  )
)
ORDER BY sk.kausi_id ASC, kk.ajankohta_alkamispaiva ASC, kk.id ASC;
```

Comment: `sor.kayttaja_id may` exist in `skp` but then `skp.sarjan_kilpailukausi_id` cannot be `sr.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id`. In other words, either `sor.kayttaja_id` does not exist in `skp` or if it does, `skp.sarjan_kilpailukausi_id` cannot be `sr.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id`.

Comment: Sorry I'm getting confused. Simple write every condition that would make you want a result and combine them with `OR`. I understood `NOT EXISTS (...)` is one such condition and `skk.sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sr.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id` is another. If this is not the case then put in the correct conditions there; the pattern is always the same.

Comment: I modified the last `OR` section and now it works perfectly. Thank you very much your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  sarjojen_rglistat.montako_huonointa_pois_lkm AS ei_huomioitavat_kilpailut_lkm
  , sarjojen_rglistat.montako_suora_nousu_lkm AS montako_suora_nousu_lkm
  , sarjojen_rglistat.montako_suora_pudotus_lkm AS montako_suora_pudotus_lkm
  , sarjojen_rglistat.montako_nousukarsinta_lkm AS montako_nousukarsinta_lkm
  , sarjojen_rglistat.montako_pudotuskarsinta_lkm AS montako_pudotuskarsinta_lkm
  , sarjojen_rglistat.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id AS vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id
  , sarjojen_rglistat.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id AS epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id
  , sarjojen_rglistojen_osakilpailut.monesko_kilpailu AS monesko_kilpailu
  , sarjojen_rglistojen_osakilpailut.sarakeotsikko AS kilpailu_sarakeotsikko
  , sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet.kayttaja_id AS kayttaja_id
  , sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet.pistemaara AS pisteet
  , sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet.kompensaatiopistemaara AS kompensaatiopisteet
  , kilpailukausien_kilpailut.id AS kilpailu_id
  , kilpailukausien_kilpailut.ajankohta_alkamispaiva AS kilpailu_alkamispaiva
  , kilpailukausien_kilpailut.kilpailunimi_virallinen AS kilpailu_nimi
  , kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.pelaaja_oma_nimi_txt AS kayttaja_nimiteksti
  , kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.pelaaja_oma_seura_lyh_txt AS kayttaja_seurateksti
  , kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.pelaaja_oma_kunta_txt AS kayttaja_kuntateksti
  , sarjojen_kilpailukaudet.kausi_id AS kausi_id

FROM (sarjojen_rglistat
    , sarjojen_rglistojen_osakilpailut
    , kilpailukausien_kilpailut
    , sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet
    , sarjojen_kilpailukaudet
    , sarjojen_kilpailukausien_kilpailusysteemit)
    /* , kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset */
    /* , sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset */

LEFT OUTER JOIN sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset
ON (sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset.sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sarjojen_rglistat.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id)

LEFT OUTER JOIN kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset
ON (sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset.kayttaja_id = kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.kayttaja_id)

WHERE
  sarjojen_rglistat.id = 4
  AND sarjojen_rglistojen_osakilpailut.rglista_id = sarjojen_rglistat.id
  AND sarjojen_rglistojen_osakilpailut.kilpailu_id = kilpailukausien_kilpailut.id
  AND sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet.kilpailu_id = kilpailukausien_kilpailut.id

  AND sarjojen_kilpailukausien_kilpailusysteemit.id = kilpailukausien_kilpailut.kauden_kilpailusysteemi_id
  AND sarjojen_kilpailukausien_kilpailusysteemit.sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sarjojen_kilpailukaudet.id

  AND kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.kayttaja_id = sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet.kayttaja_id
  AND kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.kilpailu_id = sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet.kilpailu_id

  AND kilpailukausien_kilpailut.kausi_id IS NULL
  AND kilpailukausien_kilpailut.seura_id IS NULL

  AND ((sarjojen_rglistat.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id IS NULL AND sarjojen_rglistat.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id IS NULL) || 
      (sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset.sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sarjojen_rglistat.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id AND sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset.kayttaja_id = kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.kayttaja_id) || 

      (sarjojen_rglistat.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id IS NOT NULL
      AND sarjojen_rglistat.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id NOT IN(              <!-------I had made changes to this line
        SELECT  sarjojen_rglistat.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id
        FROM    sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset
        WHERE   kayttaja_id = kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.kayttaja_id
                AND sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sarjojen_rglistat.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id
        )
      ))

  ORDER BY sarjojen_kilpailukaudet.kausi_id ASC, kilpailukausien_kilpailut.ajankohta_alkamispaiva ASC, kilpailukausien_kilpailut.id ASC
```

**`or`**

```
SELECT
  sarjojen_rglistat.montako_huonointa_pois_lkm AS ei_huomioitavat_kilpailut_lkm
  , sarjojen_rglistat.montako_suora_nousu_lkm AS montako_suora_nousu_lkm
  , sarjojen_rglistat.montako_suora_pudotus_lkm AS montako_suora_pudotus_lkm
  , sarjojen_rglistat.montako_nousukarsinta_lkm AS montako_nousukarsinta_lkm
  , sarjojen_rglistat.montako_pudotuskarsinta_lkm AS montako_pudotuskarsinta_lkm
  , sarjojen_rglistat.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id AS vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id
  , sarjojen_rglistat.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id AS epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id
  , sarjojen_rglistojen_osakilpailut.monesko_kilpailu AS monesko_kilpailu
  , sarjojen_rglistojen_osakilpailut.sarakeotsikko AS kilpailu_sarakeotsikko
  , sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet.kayttaja_id AS kayttaja_id
  , sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet.pistemaara AS pisteet
  , sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet.kompensaatiopistemaara AS kompensaatiopisteet
  , kilpailukausien_kilpailut.id AS kilpailu_id
  , kilpailukausien_kilpailut.ajankohta_alkamispaiva AS kilpailu_alkamispaiva
  , kilpailukausien_kilpailut.kilpailunimi_virallinen AS kilpailu_nimi
  , kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.pelaaja_oma_nimi_txt AS kayttaja_nimiteksti
  , kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.pelaaja_oma_seura_lyh_txt AS kayttaja_seurateksti
  , kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.pelaaja_oma_kunta_txt AS kayttaja_kuntateksti
  , sarjojen_kilpailukaudet.kausi_id AS kausi_id

FROM (sarjojen_rglistat
    JOIN sarjojen_rglistojen_osakilpailut
    JOIN kilpailukausien_kilpailut
    JOIN sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet
    JOIN sarjojen_kilpailukaudet
    JOIN sarjojen_kilpailukausien_kilpailusysteemit)
    /* , kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset */
    /* , sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset */

LEFT OUTER JOIN sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset
ON (sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset.sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sarjojen_rglistat.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id)

LEFT OUTER JOIN kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset
ON (sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset.kayttaja_id = kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.kayttaja_id)

WHERE
  sarjojen_rglistat.id = 4
  AND sarjojen_rglistojen_osakilpailut.rglista_id = sarjojen_rglistat.id
  AND sarjojen_rglistojen_osakilpailut.kilpailu_id = kilpailukausien_kilpailut.id
  AND sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet.kilpailu_id = kilpailukausien_kilpailut.id

  AND sarjojen_kilpailukausien_kilpailusysteemit.id = kilpailukausien_kilpailut.kauden_kilpailusysteemi_id
  AND sarjojen_kilpailukausien_kilpailusysteemit.sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sarjojen_kilpailukaudet.id

  AND kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.kayttaja_id = sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet.kayttaja_id
  AND kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.kilpailu_id = sarjojen_osakilpailuiden_rgpisteet.kilpailu_id

  AND kilpailukausien_kilpailut.kausi_id IS NULL
  AND kilpailukausien_kilpailut.seura_id IS NULL

  AND (
        (
            sarjojen_rglistat.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id IS NULL AND sarjojen_rglistat.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id IS NULL
        )
        || 
        (
          sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset.sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sarjojen_rglistat.vaadittu_pelaajastatus_id 
          AND sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset.kayttaja_id = kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.kayttaja_id
        ) 
        || 
        (
              sarjojen_rglistat.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id IS NOT NULL
              AND sarjojen_rglistat.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id NOT IN(
                                                                    SELECT  sarjojen_rglistat.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id
                                                                    FROM    sarjojen_kilpailukausien_pelaajastatukset
                                                                    WHERE   kayttaja_id = kayttajien_ilmoittautumiset.kayttaja_id
                                                                            AND sarjan_kilpailukausi_id = sarjojen_rglistat.epakelpo_pelaajastatus_id
                                                                )
        )
    )

  ORDER BY sarjojen_kilpailukaudet.kausi_id ASC, kilpailukausien_kilpailut.ajankohta_alkamispaiva ASC, kilpailukausien_kilpailut.id ASC
```

Try above code.

Hope this will help you.